# How to disable link time code generation in CMake

Tags: cmake

We are using CMake with the Visual Studio 2015 generator and I am trying to disable link time code generation for libraries and executables under the debug build configuration. It seems that when I modify the linker flags with

`SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${_PROJNAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG "${LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG} /LTCG:OFF")`

that CMake still generates solutions with `/LTCG:INCREMENTAL` in the linker additional options but also with `/LTGC:OFF` appended.  Does anyone know a way to turn LTCG off completely for all configurations so I can enable it just for those that we want it enabled for?

`cmake version 3.10.0-rc2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something ends up under "Additional Options" in the generated VS projects, it means CMake didn't recognize the option given (and therefore didn't replace its own default).

See [CMake's source `cmVS141LinkFlagTable.h`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/8279302110ee6eb09a16e33b3bf8f8ad4ee13b73/Source/cmVS141LinkFlagTable.h#L70):

> ```
> { "LinkTimeCodeGeneration", "", "Default", "Default", 0 },
> { "LinkTimeCodeGeneration", "LTCG:incremental", "Use Fast Link Time Code Generation", "UseFastLinkTimeCodeGeneration", 0 },
> { "LinkTimeCodeGeneration", "LTCG", "Use Link Time Code Generation", "UseLinkTimeCodeGeneration", 0 },
> { "LinkTimeCodeGeneration", "LTCG:PGInstrument", "Profile Guided Optimization - Instrument", "PGInstrument", 0 },
> { "LinkTimeCodeGeneration", "LTCG:PGOptimize", "Profile Guided Optimization - Optimization", "PGOptimization", 0 },
> { "LinkTimeCodeGeneration", "LTCG:PGUpdate", "Profile Guided Optimization - Update", "PGUpdate", 0 },
> ```

But if I look at CMake's VS 2015 defaults:

```
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS = /machine:X86
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG = /debug /INCREMENTAL
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE = /INCREMENTAL:NO
```

There is no `/LTCG:INCREMENTAL` in the defaults. So I think what you are actually looking for/what would help you is:

```
set_property(
    TARGET ${_PROJNAME} 
    APPEND_STRING 
    PROPERTY 
        LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG " /INCREMENTAL:NO"
)
```

Comment: Thank you Florian, this was helpful in discovering the issue. After stepping through CMake in debug I found we were in fact including the flag in a slightly obscure way.  Just for completeness the /INCREMENTAL and /LTCG:INCREMENTAL are different options, one controlling incremental linking and the other controlling incremental link time code generation.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually modify **CMake cache variables** `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG`, `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG`, `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG`  and `CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG` as wished.

You could remove the `/INCREMENTAL` flag from these variables.